# Hiding LWC on a lightning page entirely?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC that queries data on a record. If no data is actually returned, I want the LWC to not display at all (this is on lightning pages).

I can wrap the contents of the LWC in a `<template if:true={condition}></template>`. This works for not displaying the contents, but it still renders the component and leaves a little space where the component is on the lightning page due to a margin applied to the wrapper Salesforce wraps the LWC up in.

I don't want this margin there. I want it completely hidden. How can this be achieved? I haven't been able to really find anything to help here, just information on conditional rendering of stuff inside components.

Here is what salesforce wraps LWCs in, the div with flixpageComponent class

[image]

Comment: If you can store related records count in a field on your object then you can use set component visibility option from app builder.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5

Comment: Can you show related code, i think u r adding some styling from parent comp itself. LWC does not add any styling by itself

Comment: Is that the only way? We can't add fields for related record counts on every object.

Comment: @salesforce-sas There isn't code to show. I added the image of what Salesforce adds to the page to wrap your component. my-component is the parent component, I didn't add the div around it, Salesforce wrapped that up. And it is that div wrapper that has the margin.

Comment: you can conditionally add a display:none css rule if your condition is 0 results.

Comment: The template if:true does that. The issue is Salesforce wraps it in that flexipageCompinent class div that adds a margin regardless of if you have no content in your lwc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using the LWC component in flexi page. Then the flexi page will insert the LWC component DOM in a div as shown in image you shared.

You are getting that margin because of the flexi page `div` which will all have below CSS:

```
.flexipageComponent:not(:last-child):not(:empty) {
    margin-bottom: var(--lwc-cardSpacingMargin,0.75rem);
}
```

It means it will automatically add a margin in the bottom of component if its not the last element vertically.

> **Note that it actually does not has anything to do with LWC component by itself, this will actually be done for any other custom or standard
>   component also.**

The only way of not having the margin is by adding the visibility criteria:

[image]

Comment: My case is actually an object that looks up to the record, it isn't a drill up from the record itself. Sorry, I think I made it seem like a normal related list. So we cannot reach that object from the visibility settings on the lightning page. Is there actually no other solution that to live with an awkward margin randomly in the page? It seems like normal aura components do not have this when their contents are rendered conditionally.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Anyone find a way to adjust the bottom margin of the LWC based on logic within the LWC?  My logic is based on child records, so using the filter of the LWC to control component visibility does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing this out, looks ok so far, haven't made a style for it yet, just inline:

```
<template>
  <template if:true={hasContent}>
    <div>mycontent</div>
  </template>
  <template if:false={hasContent}>
    <div style="margin-bottom: calc(var(--lwc-cardSpacingMargin) * -1)"></div>
  </template>
</template>
```